# Google Storage Python API typeError

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, python-3.5

I am trying to use the Python client library for Google Cloud Storage. When I try to initialize the client I get a typeError. However I cannot find any reference to this.

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-c05b3b802290> in <module>()
----> 1 storage_client = storage.Client()

/opt/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py in __init__(self, project, credentials, _http, client_info)
     84         if no_project:
     85             self.project = None
---> 86         self._connection = Connection(self, client_info=client_info)
     87         self._batch_stack = _LocalStack()
     88 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/_http.py in __init__(self, client, client_info)
     31 
     32     def __init__(self, client, client_info=None):
---> 33         super(Connection, self).__init__(client, client_info)
     34 
     35         self._client_info.gapic_version = __version__

TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

My code is pretty straight forward and other cloud libraries work as expected:

```
import os
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/.google.json"
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
storage_client = storage.Client()
```

My cloud AMI is setup accordingly (service account):

```
BigQuery Admin
Storage Admin
```

Python environment is 3.5

Comment: This doesn't answer your specific question but it might be helpful.  Take a look at the upload/download google storage examples at https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb?authuser=2#scrollTo=LADpx7LReOMk

Comment: Make sure that you have the latest libraries installed. This looks like a library mismatch. Consider using virtualenv for your projects.

Comment: As @JohnHanley recommends, use a [virtualenv](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/index.html#mac-linux)

Comment: I'm using a conda environment. Just upgraded the google-cloud and google-cloud storage packages. storage.__version__ = 1.16.1. Still the same error though

Comment: In python 3.6, it works though. @JohnHanley, can you copy your comment as answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem looks like a library mismatch.

Items to look at:

1. Install/update the libraries to the latest version.
2. Install the latest Python package.
3. Use virtualenv for each program so that libraries and compiler versions are not an issue.